# gnuplot qt hidden toolbar and mouse label

Tags: gnuplot

By accident I often loose the main toolbar, likely by a kind of double right click on the toolbar.

Is there a way to get the toolbar back?

In the setting of the qt toolbar, I also found an option to put the Mouse label in the toolbar. Can this be made default?

[image][image]

Comment: Oh, it seems the mouse label settings are remembered. After restart they are in the new place.